# How to replace one table with another table in beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer

In my slides i need such a way that on mouse click the table on the current frame has to replace with another table that i need..currently my code is:

```
 \begin{table}[htb!]
\begin{center}
\onslide<2-2>\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  %table 1 rdata\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Results of RLC Circuits}
\label{tab:rlc}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\onslide<3-3>\begin{center}    
%results of Digital
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
%table two rows   
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Results of Digital Circuits}
\label{tab:dig}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

But my output is not one over another on click, its one below another on mouse click. How can i correct it??

Comment: Use \only and not \onslide.

Answer (score 2):

The `\only` command should be used for replacing things, instead of `onslide` in many cases. It must be outside of `\begin{table}...\end{table}`.

I also added a `dummy` multicolumn in the first table, such that the vertical jumping due to different row number is reduced.

```
\documentclass{beamer}%

\begin{document}%

\begin{frame}{First}
\only<2>{%
\begin{table}%
\begin{center}%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{}\tabularnewline
\hline
& & & & & \tabularnewline % Just one row
\hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Results of RLC Circuits}\label{tab:rlc}%%
\end{center}%
\end{table}%
}%


\only<3>{%
\begin{table}%
\begin{center}%    
%results of Digital
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& & & & & \tabularnewline %table two rows   
& & & & & \tabularnewline %table two rows   
\hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Results of Digital Circuits}\label{tab:dig}%
\end{center}%
\end{table}%
}%


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```